# ArrayList to Hashmap Conversion

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

This was originally a arraylist which I converted into a hashmap however I get errors
in method add shape from switch (type) , I changed the shapes.add to shapes.put however there is still an error, help is appreciated thanks.

```
    switch (type) { // getting errors here on all cases 
        case "Polygon":
            shapes.put(new RegularPolygon(name, val1, val2, x, y));
            break;
        case "Rectangle":
            shapes.put(new Rectangle(name, val1, val2, x, y));
            break;
        case "CharL":
            shapes.put(new LCharacter(name, val1, val2, x, y));
            break;
        default:
            errorMessage = "Invalid type " + type;
            break;
```

Comment: Always provide the exact and complete error message you get. And always read the javadoc of the methods you're trying to use.

Comment: Why did you drop the ArrayList in favor of a Map? I don't think you need a Map in here.

Comment: In getShapes, your creating two arrays. You can remove the first statment.

Comment: @ClaudioFernandez its part of an assignment to do so

Answer (score 2):

The Map.put() function takes **two** arguments: first the key, then the value. You're only providing the value.

Your code should look something like this:

```
shapes.put("someKey", someShape);
```

For more info, consult the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: What would it be in my case? how do I know which one is key which one is value?

Comment: That's entirely up to you and the context of your code. What is a Shape's key? Perhaps its name?

Comment: It still gave me an error when I tried to do that, do I need to set the value ? before I can enter it ?

Comment: What error? With what code? You need to be much more specific with your questions.

Comment: 'code' case "Polygon":
                shapes.put(type , RegularPolygon));
                break;
'code'

This is what I changed it to now I get the error expression expected

Comment: What is RegularPolygon? Is it a class? It needs to be an **instance** of a class.